# Baked normals are colorful?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, baking, normal-map

I have fixed a problem I had with baking normals onto a low poly model and have gotten my normal map.

Baking the map to my low poly model didn't work no matter what I tried, so instead I just baked the high poly, and it worked! But I have a new problem: the normal map is good but there are these weird colored artifacts that are around my bump. I can use this map and it works fine, but for presentation purposes I would like it to be all purple-blue.

[image: Screenshot]

How can I get rid of them so that the whole thing is purple-blue instead of green, yellow, and red? If I can get rid of them then I can finally get a good normal map. To me, it looks like I need a higher ray distance value but I am not using selected to active; it's just a 4k texture bake with margin set to 16. Everything else is set to default. Could i maybe draw over it in photoshop? Please help

Comment: When you created your "Bake3" image, did you select the "Alpha" checkbox?

Comment: @DaleCieslak yes i did.

Comment: So did you try creating a new image with Alpha *un*selected?  I'd also try increasing your Ray Distance.

Comment: @DaleCieslak  fixed the problem by just baking on my high poly, but now i have a new problem^^

Comment: Do not edit one question with a new question. Add answer with what worked for you on previous question. Then ask a new question where include what is above.

Comment: kind of too late for that..i wrote a lot of stuff

Comment: That's quite easy to do. Stackexchange has edit history if you haven't noticed - that "edited "some time" ago" link below your post. Editing question with new question is wrong accodring to the rules of the site - that's all

Comment: well this hasn't been removed yet..in 5 hours i am adding a bounty of 50 rep for someone to answer this question

Comment: It's hard to answer without seeing your model, but your question is a bit silly, wanting a normal map of a given color.  The colors represent vectors in the x, y, and z direction and so the shape determines the color.  If you want it mostly blue then make a mostly flat model.  Harsh bumps will give red and green colors, and possibly you have flipped normals in parts of your model?  Also did you bake in Tangent Space or Object space?  Object space maps tend to be more colorful.